# reuse an already established connection with win32 gvim

Tags: windows, ssh, vim, cygwin, putty

How can I reuse an ssh connection on windows? Ive been using these settings in my _vimrc for sftp and noticed that each time I browse or try to edit a file with netrw, a new connection is created which takes an awful long time.

```
let g:netrw_cygwin = 0
let g:netrw_ssh_cmd  = '"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe" -batch -T -ssh'
let g:netrw_scp_cmd  = '"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\pscp.exe"  -batch -q -scp'
let g:netrw_sftp_cmd = '"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\pscp.exe"  -batch -q -sftp'
let g:netrw_list_cmd = '"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe" myuser@mysite.com ls -Fa '
```

I have also tried to use cyg-wrapper.sh to avoid this problem

```
:e scp://myuser@mysite.com:22//home
```

but a cmd window opens up with this error

```
/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/scp -q -P 22 "myuser@mysite
.com:/home" "C:\cygwin\tmp\VIA3996.tmp""
The system cannot find the path specified.
shell returned 1
Hit any key to close this window...
```

I tried scp because I didnt know how to use a private key for sftp at the time within cygwin

Answer (score 0):

According to [keeping ssh connections open on windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/531443/keeping-ssh-connections-open-on-windows), PuTTY doesn't support connection sharing. So, try using one of the mentioned OpenSSH ports instead with the configuration mentioned in the question.

Comment: apparently, cygwin does not support connection sharing http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-02/msg00366.html which OpenSSh_for_windows also uses

Comment: apparently Putty does in version 0.66 and possibly before, since I came here looking for info on the PuTTY message "Reusing a shared connection to this server"