# Using SCP over a existing SSH Chain? Possible?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, scp

SCP establishes a new connection when copying files, which sometimes can make it hard if there are firewalls involved.

For example,

**Host-A <--> Host-B <--> Host-C <--> Host-D**

- Host-A is connected to Host-B via SSH, and then Host-B is connected
  to Host-C via SSH, and then to Host-D.
- Host-A cannot connect to other computers other than Host-B, Host-B can only connect to Host-A and Host-C, Host-C can only connect to Host-B and Host-D, and last Host-D can only connect to Host-C.

The command (on Host-D) **scp /home/user/file Host-A:/home/user/newfile** will attempt to create a new SSH tunnel between the two, which is not what i want. I want the existing SSH tunnel chain to copy the file back through the previous hosts until it reaches Host-A.

How can i do this?

Comment: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949316/can-i-use-an-existing-ssh-connection-and-execute-scp-over-that-tunnel-without-re

Comment: Related: [PuTTY does not support connection sharing](https://superuser.com/q/653998/86708)

Answer (score 0):

You can re-use existing connections. Either use command-line switch `-M`, or (client) config option `ControlMaster`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20410383/712526) on StackOverflow for details.

I've used this extensively, combined with `ControlPersist` to to close the connection only after a delay. This avoids the connection time you would otherwise incur, and drastically improves performance when you're closing and re-connecting multiple times (as I often do during interactive use).

Do note that it does not work very well for connecting to some hosts — GitHub, for example — so you may need to explicitly exclude certain hosts from using this option, if you set it up as your default.

Comment: Oh, and if the connection hangs, as it does occasionally, you can simply delete the `ControlMaster` file for the connection, and re-connect.